# How do I set the selected item in a NSPathControl in PopUp style?

Tags: cocoa

I have `NSPathControl` with pop up style. When I try to choose other 'predefined' location - no changes occurs.

Example:

```
-------------
choice...
-------------
Some macBook
Some desktop
Some HD
and etc.
-------------
```

By default, for example, 'Some macBook' is selected, but when I try to select a different one, for example 'Some HD', there is no change: The pop up menu disappears and default selection shows the same.

Answer (score 1):

Setup and connect NSPathControl

.h

```
 @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSPathControl pathControl;
```

.m

```
 -(void) awakeFromNib {
 // Give Path control some value
      [_pathControl setURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/Users/Username/MyPath" isDirectory:YES]];
 }
```

Connect action in IB.

***NOTE:  I noticed if you connect using a binding object this action will not return values.
*** If your using bindings then a solution using some KVC trappings would be necessary.

```
-(IBAction) pathControlClicked:(id)sender {
NSPathControl* pathCntl = (NSPathControl *)sender;

NSPathComponentCell *component = [pathCntl clickedPathComponentCell];   // find the path component selected
[pathCntl setURL:[component URL]];          // set the url to the path control


_ivarStringVariable=component.URL.path;

// If you want to configure pathComponentCells here is place to do it.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this behavior exists, it's very confusing for users.

I generally just "disable" it, by implementing a delegate method:

```
- (void)pathControl:(NSPathControl *)pathControl willPopUpMenu:(NSMenu *)menu {
    // We don't want to show the useless "parent folders" menu items, as they are very confusing.
    while ([[menu itemArray] count] >= 4) {
        [menu removeItemAtIndex:3];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!